# PHP Get URL with Parameter

Tags: php

I want to get a URL and its parameters. Example:

```
www.someweb.com/somepage.php?id=10
```

How to get only `somepage.php?id=10`?

I'm already tried `REQUEST_URI` and `PHP_SELF` but it only gives me `www.someweb.com/somepage.php` or `somepage.php`. What I want to is just the page name and its parameter(s).

Answer (score 78, accepted):

```
basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

This will return all URLs with page name. (e.g.: `index.php?id=1&name=rr&class=10`).

Comment: This works in your case, but if the url path was 'deeper' ( www.someweb.com/somewhere/somepage.php?id=10 for example ), it would still only return the last part: 'somepage.php?id=10'

Comment: Your code return last part only `example.com/page/article` and return `article`, how to make so it should return `page/article`

Comment: @RajeevRanjanSharma maybe you could use `REQUEST_URI` and `implode` by `/` and return 2 last array?

Answer (score 31):

for complette URL with protocol, servername and parameters:

```
 $base_url = ( isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS']=='on' ? 'https' : 'http' ) . '://' .  $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
 $url = $base_url . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
```

Answer (score 8):

`$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` for the page name and `$_GET['id']` for a specific parameter.

try `print_r($_GET);` to print out all the parameters.

for your request `echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?id=".$_GET['id'];`

return all the parameters `echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];`

Comment: there's no way without use $_GET[id]? Because sometimes I use 2 or 3 parameters too. (I just think to make it simpler than $_GET, but if it only the way to make what I want, it's okay)

Comment: if you are using more than one paramater, then use create array like, id,id2,id3 and use while loop..

Comment: There is a way, use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`

Answer (score 1):

```
function curPageName() {
 return substr($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],strrpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],"/")+1);
}
echo "The current page is ".curPageName()."?".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```

This will get you page name , it will get the string after the last slash

Comment: Nope. it doesn't works. using basename finally. Thanks for answer

Answer (score 0):

Here's probably what you are looking for: [php-get-url-query-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469767/php-get-url-query-string). You can combine it with other suggested `$_SERVER` parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very thorough function I use to get the full URL:

```
function get_full_url( bool $include_query = true ) {
    $protocol = ( ! empty( $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) && strtolower( $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) !== 'off' )
        || ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] ) && strtolower( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] ) === 'https' )
        || ( ! empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_FRONT_END_HTTPS'] ) && strtolower( $_SERVER['HTTP_FRONT_END_HTTPS'] ) !== 'off' )
        || ( isset( $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] ) && intval( $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] ) === 443 ) ? 'https' : 'http';
    $uri = $protocol . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    return $include_query ? $uri : str_replace( '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], '', $uri );
}
```