# How can I get the path of the fetch function in the php file?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a JavaScript function to fetch data from the backend

```
async getAllExpensesByUser() {
    let response = await fetch("router.php/getAll");
    return response.json();
}
```

in router.php how can I get the path "/getAll" so I can retrieve data accordingly?

Comment: you should use `router.php?getAll=1` path and get it with `$_GET["getAll"]` in php

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get uri

```
basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

for more information visit [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13427177/php-get-url-with-parameter) or [php documantion](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)