# hiding get variable in url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, get

I have a url like

```
localhost/index?id=2
```

How do I hide the id part by using htaccess and just show:

```
localhost/index/2
```

Comment: most people want `localhost/index/2` or `localhost/2`

Comment: @Dagon it doesn't matter whatever it is I just want to get rid of the `id=`

Comment: @Prix not working for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to catch the query string, you need to use either `%{QUERY_STRING}` or `%{THE_REQUEST}`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect /index?id=2 to /index/2
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\?id=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /index?%1 [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [QSA,L]
```

Given that you don't have other rules that may conflict with your needs, this should work just fine.

Once you confirm its working you can change from `302`, to `301` but in order to avoid caching, tests should be always done using `302`.

Another way using `%{THE_REQUEST}` would be like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect /index?id=2 to /index/2
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\?id=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /index/%1? [R=302,L]

# Internally forward /index/2 to /index.php?id=2
RewriteRule ^index/([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I have `RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
` in .htaccess and when I add your code it doesn't work. I still see the full url.

Comment: @Lmxc see the update on the first rule  I've posted above, try that. I have tested it with your rule and it works just fine when you access `http://localhost/index?id=200` it changes to `http://localhost/index?200`.

Comment: now the `id` isn't being passed through the url. I am getting `id` as empty.

Comment: @Lmxc because you asked to remove it, in order to get it now you need to use http://stackoverflow.com/a/8469777/342740 from your PHP or if you wish you can change the URL using the 2nd example which will pass the id back just fine.

Comment: @Lmxc because you're using relative path, for example `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/my.css">` and with relative path it assumes that the css folder is on the closest folder of the URL in this case it becomes `/index/css/my.css` in order to avoid this you need to use absolute path like this `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/css/my.css">`, same goes for images, JavaScript, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-+_%*?]+)/?$    index.php?id=$1     [L]
```

([A-Za-z0-9-+_%*?]+) <-- this part with in the brackets is used as regular expression means you are looking for any Character from A to z and from a to z and any number from 0 to 9 and symbol - , +,_,%,*,? and the + sign after the closing square bracket means more than one .

In short You are asking to for which is ([in here]+) and it's more than one ,if however you remove the + symbol after the bracket it'll return only the first character

Comment: can you put  the code of your .htaccess file  so that  i can  check it solve the problem