# Pass a value from a jQuery script to a rendered page

Tags: jquery, wordpress, templates

This is my code for dropdown

```
?><select id="land_unit" name="unit_name" ><?php
$result=$wpdb->get_results("select * from unit");
                 foreach($result as $row) {
                  $unit_id=$row->unit_id;
                  $unit_name=$row->unit_name;     
                 ?>
<option value="<?php echo $unit_id; ?>" <?php if($land_unit== $unit_id){ echo 
 'selected="selected"';} ?>><?php echo $unit_name; ?></option>
<?php  } ?></select><?php
```

This is my code in js file

```
$("#land_unit").on('change', function()
{
 var unit_id=$(this).val();
//alert(id);
});
```

I want to pass var unit_id to my template file in wordpress. So how do I do that??
My url is like this abc.com/abc so in that case how?

Comment: have you tried using a query string?

Comment: no..I dont know how to do that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469767/get-url-query-string or google it. It's rather a simple method. If you have difficulty, then ask after you've given it a shot.

Comment: where do I use $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']

Comment: @ericosg can you explain further. I saw that link.

Comment: one site generates the data to send to another website. so the sender needs to call the other file with a ?query=string added to the end of the url and the receiving site needs to access this by $_GET['query']