# How to get PHP to read URL

Tags: php, html

I was wondering how I could get a HTML/PHP file to read the URL,

What I mean is, Let's say I had a Search function in (index.php) that had a button saying Show Bans which opened a New Windows but when clicking Show Bans it sent a link to 'banaccount.php?id=(idhere) how can I get the PHP file (Banaccount.php) to recognise the ID and have it as a PHP function ($id = (idhere) );?

Comment: Look into GET super global

Comment: http://php.net/reserved.variables.get

Comment: That kind of question you could find the answer easily, no need to rush and open a new question,,,heres the link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469767/get-url-query-string

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if (!isset($_GET['id'])) { /* problem */ exit; }
$id = $_GET['id'];
//... Do something with $id
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check to see if "id" has a value and assign it to a variable. It is also very important that you be safe and not attempt to grab the raw value, as any user on your site can insert anything unsafe to the URL. Use PHP's [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) function to convert the unsafe characters to HTML entities.

```
$id = null;
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = htmlspecialchars($_GET['id'], ENT_QUOTES, true);
}
```