# PHP Request uri get string parts after question mark

Tags: php

When using `$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]` am getting a string like following one

```
"/stardigitalprint/index.php?route=product/product&path=59_61&product_id=50"
```

How to take the parts after question mark, ie

> "product/product&path=59_61&product_id=50"

Your help is much appreciated 
Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

The server variable `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` should contain what you are looking for.

Comment: Is that a question to OP :P

Comment: Dire ct copy paste of here?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469767/get-url-query-string

Comment: No I just wrote that answer, after several years of PHP development you would think I remember how to access the query string :-) - albeit I used the same word 'contains' .. I see your logic.

Comment: U getting offended right.... I was just wondering how the answers have the same wordings

Comment: No you haven't offended me, don't worry.

Comment: @RichardAdnams Thank you so much for your code. Its working. Now am getting   "route=product/product&path=59_61&product_id=50". I want only following part "product/product&path=59_61&product_id=50". sorry for my mistake

Comment: Excellent, you should have a look here http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php there is a built in function that will parse the query string into an array allowing you to access the parts you need by key.

Answer (score 2):

```
$parts = explode("?", $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]);
echo $parts[1];
```

You'll need to check whether the uri has some get params or not

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "/stardigitalprint/index.php?route=product/product&path=59_61&product_id=50";
echo substr($str , strpos($str , "?") + 1);
```

[Please have a look :](http://codepad.org/KVnVknGm)

So I guess this will work for you.

`echo substr($_SERVER[REQUEST_URI] , strpos($_SERVER[REQUEST_URI] , "?") + 1);`

Answer (score 0):

The parts after the question mark are called "Query String".
There are plenty of answeres [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469767/get-url-query-string) if someone is still getting to this page