# How can I get URL (with some parameters)?

Tags: php

I have a form on page, with url like this:

```
site.com/form.index.html?ref=https://login....
```

And I get page URL via this code:

```
http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]
```

But as result I get not full URL, just this:

```
site.com/form.index.html
```

How can I get full URL?

Comment: Look up what the $_GET variable is doing in PHP

Comment: You need to add the query string: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469767/get-url-query-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to add the query string:

```
$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]$_SERVER[QUERY_STRING]";
```

Additionally, you may replace the *http* bit with `$_SERVER[REQUEST_SCHEME]`:

```
"$_SERVER[REQUEST_SCHEME]://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]$_SERVER[QUERY_STRING]"
```