# How to get all query strings from the url? PHP

Tags: php, mysql, function, variables

I'm trying to get the full url together with all the query strings of this url

```
http://localhost/test/searchprocess.php?categ=vessel&keyword=ves&search-btn=Search&page=5
```

I tried to use this function but it doesn't give me all of the query strings. It only saves the first query string.

```
function getCurrentURL() {
        $currentURL = (@$_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "https://" : "http://";
        $currentURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
        if($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80" && $_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "443") {
            $currentURL .= ":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"];
        } 
        $currentURL .= $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
        return $currentURL;
    }
```

When I `echo getcurrentURL();` it only gives me `http://localhost/test/searchprocess.php?categ=vessel`

How can I be able to get the full url?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get URL query string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469767/get-url-query-string)

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is almost right. Try this:

```
$base_url = ( isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS']=='on' ? 'https' : 'http' ) . '://' .  $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$url = $base_url . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
```

Comment: Still the same. I already figured out now what's the problem. Since i'm trying to pass a variable with the url to another page using GET method. Maybe the ampersand and equal signs are conflicting. I just used session now to pass it. Thanks btw!

Answer (score 0):

You want the [`parse_url()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

```
$url = 'http://username:password@hostname:9090/path?arg=value#anchor';
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY));
```

which returns

```
string(9) "arg=value"
```