# How can I get query string values on a AMP site?

Tags: amp-html

Is there a way to retrieve query string values from an AMP-HTML Site and store them in a cookie or use them in a link?

Example:

1. User clicks on an ad `www.example.com/amp?foo=bar`
2. Open the AMP Site
3. Click on a link and come to the checkout - not AMP `www.example.com/checkout?foo=bar`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get URL query string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469767/get-url-query-string)

Comment: Is not working on a HTML-AMP site?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but you just to preprocess it on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [QUERY_PARAM](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-var-substitutions.md)

```
https://expample.amp.com?slug=1234abc
```

```
<a
  href="https://example.com?abc=QUERY_PARAM(slug)"
  data-amp-replace="QUERY_PARAM"
  >Go to my site</a
>
```

```
<amp-list id="time"
            layout="fixed-height"
            height="18"
            src="https://api.exemple.com/posts?slug=QUERY_PARAM(slug)"
            binding="refresh"
            data-amp-replace="QUERY_PARAM"
            single-item
            items=".">
    <template type="amp-mustache">
      ...
    </template>
  </amp-list>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use `QUERY_PARAM()` variable to get the variables in amp-pixel or amp-analytics.

https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-var-substitutions.md#query_param

Answer (score 3):

Just extending Avi's answer. You can also use it in forms and anchor tags () like this:

```
<form method="post" id="form1" role="search" action-xhr="https://example.com/path/to/something" target="_top" on="submit-success:msg-thanks-sticky;submit-error:msg-sorry-sticky">
[...]
<input type="hidden" class="inputHidden" name="param1" value="QUERY_PARAM(param1)" data-amp-replace="QUERY_PARAM">
<input type="hidden" class="inputHidden" name="param2" value="QUERY_PARAM(param2)" data-amp-replace="QUERY_PARAM">

[...]
</form>
```

Pay attention to the "data-amp-replace" attribute, needed for this specific tags.

For detailed information:
- https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-var-substitutions.md#substitution-timing
- https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-form/amp-form.md#variable-substitutions

Answer (score 0):

On your non-AMP checkout page, you could use JavaScript to read `document.referrer` and extract the query string that was passed to the AMP landing page.

For example:

1. Load https://www.ampproject.org/?foo=bar.
2. Click an arbitrary link like the one to https://www.ampproject.org/docs/get_started/about-amp.html.
3. Open the JavaScript console.
4. Examine `document.referrer` and see that it contains `"https://www.ampproject.org/?foo=bar"`.

Note that [`document.referrer` may be empty](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec15.html#sec15.1.3) when an HTTPS page links to an HTTP URL.