# Open details page in AMP with dynamic data (get query string from url)

Tags: javascript, html, json, amp-html, accelerated-mobile-page

I'm starting with AMP - Accelerated Mobile Pages, and I've some doubts according to dynamic JSON data.

I've a `amp-list` with a JSON retrieved by an API, it works fine, my question is:

How do I open the details page for the list items?

Should I use an `a` tag like this one?

```
<a href="details.html?ref={{ref}}">list item</a>
```

If yes, how do I get the `ref` token from the URL?

Comment: Maybe an answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43748634/add-javascript-in-amp-pages) question can help you

Comment: Refer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40035802/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-on-a-amp-site