# How to pass parameter between pages in this code?

Tags: php

How to pass the parameter between pages? Below is the code. How should I code the parameter by id in this code?

```
  function addRowHandlers() {
  var tbody = $("#employee-click"); 
   tbody. each(function() {
   $(this).on('click', function() { 
  window.location.href = "detail.php";

   })
   })
   }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469767/get-url-query-string

Comment: You should use HTML query strings, the above comment has a link with an answer about how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to pass variables securely, that the end user can't modify, to another page your should use PHP Sessions and store the value in there.

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Answer (score 1):

You can set id as follows

```
window.location.href = "detail?id="+id;
```

And get in detail.php

```
var url =new URL (window.location.href);

var id = url.searchParams.get("id");
```

Or use

```
$_GET['id']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass variables to other page by query strings.
As in your code add this

```
window.location.href = "detail.php?var="+myvariable;
```

And you can get that from detail.php like this

```
$_GET['var']
```

Comment: but if i want to click by the row how to code that?                                 
 the code :<a href="member_detail.php? memberid= <?php echo $row['memberid']; ?>">Detail</a> is for button only.