# Unable to append query to url ending like /?user

Tags: php, get, query-string

www.something.com/?user, where "user" is a php file, is there any way to add query string parameters to it?

Have failed with:

www.something.com/?user?id=1

www.something.com/?user&id=1

www.something.com/?user/id=1

Have seen this topic: [Get URL query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469767/get-url-query-string)

but this is not exactly what I'm after...thanks

Comment: the `?` in the url separates the path and the parameters. if you want many parameters, you have to use `&` to separate them. `www.something.com/?user&id=1` is perfectly valid. this url has two parameters : `user` with no value and `id` with value `1`

Comment: Do you have some sort of routing going on to convert `user` into a valid php file name?

Comment: thanks Crozet, unfortunately it's not working.

Comment: RiggsFolly, no - do you have any advice how to do that?

Comment: what do you mean by "it does not work" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do it with the php extension intact would be:

```
www.something.com/user.php?id=1
```

You then use:

```
$userID = $_GET['id'];
```

If you want to drop the PHP extension, you can do this with a rewrite in the htaccess:  This is pretty generic as it depends on your web-server, but something like:

```
RewriteRule ^www\.something\.com/user\.php$ /www.something.com/user?&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Or you could just drop using the PHP extension on all of the files to keep it neat using something like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

This will rewrite all of your php extensions so this:

```
something.com/someFileName
```

Will automagically be read as

```
something.com/someFileName.php
```

To which you can still use:

```
something.com/someFileName?someQueryParameter=someValue
```