# How to get the variable values from the current page url in php

Tags: php, http, url, query-string

Suppose the URL is `https://www.example.com/page.php?id=1&title=this+is+a+sample+content`.

Now my question is to retrieve the values of id and title here

Comment: For retrieving query params, use `$_GET`. See http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get URL query string parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8469767/608639), [How to get parameters from a URL string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11480763/608639), etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the URL params with `$_GET` in PHP. You may also have a look at the [$_GET documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).

In your case it would be:

```
<?php

echo $_GET["title"];
```

Or the better variant with an `if` statement.

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET["title"])) {
  echo htmlspecialchars($_GET["title"]);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on same page `page.php`, then you can get variable like this:

```
<?php

    $id    = $_GET['id'];

    $title = $_GET['title'];

?>
```

So, this will output is

```
id = 1

title = this is a sample content
```