# Collect the variable from a link php

Tags: php

I want to collect the variables from a link
http://X1.com/track.php?name=john&invoiveid=222&amont=33&address=......&email=john@gmail.com
First question can encode this link so the variables by encodes ? and how ?
i want that track.php to collect those variable and re use it
like :

```
$name
$invoiveid
$amont
$address
$email
```

Comment: You have your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/17685189/14066311

Answer (score 0):

use  [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) for that.

```
<?php

$url = "https://example.com/test/1234?email=xyz4@test.com&testin=123";
$query_str = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($query_str, $query_params);
print_r($query_params);
?>
```

result:

```
Array ( [email] => xyz4@test.com [testin] => 123 )
```

The result is an array

```
$query_params['email'] contains your email
```