# Capture dynamic data thrown on my PHP website

Tags: php, post, get

actually I am using a third party service that sends data through GET on my website dynamically, i.e. like a notification.

I want to get that request and process it. I have used requestbin.com and they were using web sockets I guess. But I need to use use PHP for processing.

Anybody knows anything?

Comment: I want to do that like in requestbin.com

Comment: To access GET, use `$_GET`, and if you don’t know the key, use the [`$_SERVER`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8469777/231316) variable.

Comment: No my friend  I am getting request dynamically anytime like i am getting a get request each time i am getting an incoming call.

Comment: Web servers get dynamic requests all the time. I’m not really clear on what your problem is.

Comment: Bro i want to create a notification system for incoming call as i am getting a get request for the same
I need to send my frontend a notification as soon i receive a get or post request