# custom get query from url function in php

Tags: php, string, url, get, url-parsing

I wrote a function getQuery($param) which returns data from the

```
function getQuery($param){
    if(!empty(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_QUERY))){
    $queries = parse_url(strtok($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_QUERY))['query'];
    parse_str($queries, $query);
    return $query[$param];
    }
}

//url = https://example.com/test?name=Arun&email=arun@example.com

echo getQuery("name"); // Output will be:Arun
```

But if the URL parameters contain "6" this function is only returning query data until that character

```
//i.e. if URL = https://example.com/test?name=Arun&email=arun056@example.com
echo getQuery("email");   //  Expected Output: arun056@example.com
                        //  Original Output: arun05
```

Is there any solution to fix this bug? Someone, please help

> Edit:

Thanks for the reply. I found another method to write this function

```
<?php
function testgetQuery($param){
    $queries = explode("&",explode("?",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])[1]);
    $getQuery = [];
    foreach($queries as $query){
        $getQuery[explode("=", $query)[0]] = explode("=", $query)[1];
    }
    return $getQuery[$param];
}
```

This worked pretty well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is a very complicated way to get query parameters. You can simply use `$_GET['email']` to get the email. You should also apply a default in case it is not set.

```
$email = $_GET['email'] ?? false;
```

If you wanted to turn this into a helper function,

```
function getQuery($key, $default = ''): string 
{
    return $_GET[$key] ?? $default;
}

$email = getQuery('email');
```

---

The reason it is being truncated if you have a `6` in the query string is because of this line. [strtok](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php) will tokenize a string by a delimiter but you have provided `PHP_URL_QUERY` as the delimiter. That is a predefined PHP constant and has a value of `6`. So strtok will split the string on `6`.

```
strtok($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_QUERY)
```

[image]

---

> Yes, I can use $_GET. but, I developed a simple routing system. In
> this $GET is not working. So, I had to write this getQuery() function.

That doesn't make a whole lotta sense to me, but if you want to use `parse_url` you can do something like this. But know that `$_GET` works to get everything after the `?` too.

```
function getQuery($key, $default = ''): string
{
    $parts = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    parse_str($parts['query'], $query);
    
    return $query[$key] ?? $default;
}

$email = getQuery('email');
```

Comment: Yes, I can use $_GET. but, I developed a simple routing system. In this $GET is not working. So, I had to write this getQuery() function.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried another method to fix it. ```function testgetQuery($param){
    $queries = explode("&",explode("?",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])[1]);
    $getQuery = [];
    foreach($queries as $query){
        $getQuery[explode("=", $query)[0]] = explode("=", $query)[1];
    }
    return $getQuery[$param];
}```

Comment: I added an edit.

Comment: _"but, I developed a simple routing system. In this $GET is not working."_ - why not, how did you manage to break it? You are still taking the original query string contents from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, only you are parsing it yourself - so why should PHP's default mechanism, that would be doing pretty much the same thing, not work?

Answer (score 0):

First, you must know what exactly your code doing. Like why you need a function to use?

> But if the URL parameters contain "6" this function is only returning query data until that character

Why that happened?

By the definition of `strtok` from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strtok.asp).

> The strtok() function splits a string into smaller strings (tokens).

Where the second parameter is used to:

> Specifies one or more split characters

So, why the email only returned before the character of "6"?
It is because the value of `PHP_URL_QUERY` is `6` [reference](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/0e65e433a9a439b8249ee18c53b82ce06e25ad5f/ext/standard/url.h#L47).

So this is like we wrote:

```
strtok($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 6)
```

And then from the URL you give, it going to this:

```
strtok('https://example.com/test?name=Arun&email=arun@example.com', 6)
// You got https://example.com/test?name=Arun&email=arun05
```

It splitted the URL by the character of 6.

---

So, for the final words, if you just want to get the query parameter from a URL string. I think it is easy to find already answered questions.

Please check the link below:

1. [Get URL query string parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469767/get-url-query-string-parameters)
2. [How can I get parameters from a URL string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480763/how-can-i-get-parameters-from-a-url-string)