# How to retrieve query parameters from GET request using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, get

Below is my GET request. I am trying to retrieve the client_id and redirect_uri parameters.

```
https://sdkapp.example.com:8443/central-login/index.html?client_id=dtvClient&redirect_uri=https://www.example3.com:443/callback
```

And then utilize those values, in a embedded js script within the same html page.

```
Config.set({
  clientId: //fetched query parameter for client_id
  redirectUri: // fetched query parameter for redirect_uri
  });
```

Comment: In the browser or on the server? Normally you'd be doing this on the server. If on the server, what technology are you using server-side? (Presumably not jQuery! :-) )

Comment: I am doing this on browser. The page is a SPA with embedded js. Using Vanilla JS only for retrieving this value from url.

Comment: So why the [tag:jquery] tag? Most people who say "vanilla JavaScript" mean "without any libs like jQuery".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is on the client you can use [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) and [searchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

```js
// const url = new URL(location.href); // uncomment and delete next line
const url = new URL("https://sdkapp.example.com:8443/central-login/index.html?client_id=dtvClient&redirect_uri=https://www.example3.com:443/callback"); // for example

const obj = {
  "clientId": url.searchParams.get("client_id"),
  "redirectUri": url.searchParams.get("redirect_uri")
};
console.log(obj)

// Config.set(obj)
```

If on the server: for example node also has [URL](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html)

And here is an answer for php: [Get URL query string parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469767/get-url-query-string-parameters)

Comment: I'd think getting the query string params in the browser would be an often-repeated duplicate. Since the OP has confirmed they do indeed mean the browser, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript) for instance.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I agree, but that specific dupe is SO FULL OF CODE - why on earth would one use a Proxy to call the URL api???

Comment: There are other answers there. (I agree, the proxy thing is just dumb.) The point is, as you sometimes put it, "huge dupe" :-)

Comment: I am receiving error on console like "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')" for the below line of code.                                                                             var url_string =window.location.href;
     var client = url_string.searchParams.get("client_id");

Comment: @KaranNayyar That is because you are not using URL: `const url = new URL(window.location.href); const client = url.searchParams.get("client_id");`