# How to read url id param in PHP Api from Angular DELETE method

Tags: php, angular, api

I am using delete method in angular and sending ID parameter to PHP REST Api but it is returning null. So how can I read params in PHP side?

**delete.php**

```
<?php
include('connection.php');

$extract = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$idCourse = $extract->courses->idCourse;

$sql = "DELETE FROM courses WHERE idCourse='$idCourse'";
$conn->query($sql);
?>
```

**course.component.html**

```
<form>
  <label for='courseName'>Course name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="courseName" [(ngModel)]="course.courseName" />
  <label for='coursePrice'>Course price:</label>
  <input type="text" name="coursePrice" [(ngModel)]="course.coursePrice" />
  <button (click)="register(this.course)">Register</button>
  <button (click)="update(this.course)">Update</button>
  <button (click)="delete(this.course)">Delete</button>
</form>

<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Course Name</td>
    <td>Price</td>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor='let course of courses'>
    <td>{{ course.courseName }}</td>
    <td>{{ course.coursePrice }}</td>
    <td><button (click)="listOne(course)">Select course</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**listOne()**

```
  listOne(course: Course) {
    this.course.idCourse = course.idCurso;
    this.course.courseName = course.courseName;
    this.course.coursePrice = course.coursePrice;
  }
```

**course.component.ts**

```
 delete(course: Course) {
    this.courseService.delete(course).subscribe((res: Course[]) => {
      this.courses = res;
      this.course = new Course();
      this.list();
    });
  }
```

**course.service.ts**

```
  delete(course: Course): Observable<Course[]> {
    const params = new HttpParams().set('idCourse', course.idCourse!.toString());
    return this.http.delete(`${this.url}delete.php`, { params: params }).pipe(map((res: any) => {
      this.courses.filter((c) => c.idCourse !== curso.idCourse);
      return this.courses;
    }))
  }
```

**PHP error**

```
[Wed Nov  9 18:13:12 2022] PHP Warning:  Attempt to read property "courses" on null in /var/www/api/backend/delete.php on line 5
[Wed Nov  9 18:13:12 2022] PHP Warning:  Attempt to read property "idCourses" on null in /var/www/api/backend/delete.php on line 5
```

**PS: Other methods such as POST PUT and GET using similar JSON read method in PHP (json_decode) are working perfectly. Only DELETE method is returning null.**

Comment: People seem to have differing opinions here, https://stackoverflow.com/q/299628/1427878, on whether a DELETE request should have a request body in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the QueryParam `idCourse` to your request.

In your php code you are using `$extract = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));` which will read the request body (**not the query params**) and parse it. Since you didn't pass a request body from angular (and probably shouldn't since this is a `DELETE` call, you should instead read the actual query param on server side.

There are different options to actually read a query string in PHP (see here: [Get URL query string parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469767/get-url-query-string-parameters)), but here is an example:

```
$queries = array();
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $queries);
$idCourse = $queries['idCourse']

$sql = "DELETE FROM courses WHERE idCourse='$idCourse'";
$conn->query($sql);
```

**Big warning**

You are basically making your application vulnerable to SQL injections if you directly pass your query param to an SQL query. You should take a look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php to see how you can avoid this.